# Getting Weird Outputs When Printing my 2D Array with Random Numbers, Specifically on Row 6 and 7

Tags: c++, arrays, random

My output for the following code has something weird happening on rows 6 and 7, Row 6 always has 3 zeros as the last entries and row 7 always has first 4 zeros and then a large number ~480000. I dont know what is causing this and I need the code to print a full 2D array with 7 rows and 5 columns all with random numbers from 1-100.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
//Function precalls
int random_num(int r);
void printArray(int* arr, int r, int c);

int main()
{
    const int length = 5; //Sets the length of the array segments
    int ran = 0;
    int i, j;
    int r = 7; //Declares number of rows
    int c = 5; //Declares number of columns
    int arr[7][5]; //Initializes the array
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = random_num(ran);
        }
    }
    printArray((int*)arr, r, c);
}

void printArray(int* arr, int r, int c) //Prints the Array
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            cout << *(arr + i * c + j) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int random_num(const int r) //Assigns random numbers to Array
{
    int ran = 0; //Sets the number to zero before generation
    ran = rand() % 100 + 1;
    return ran;
}
```

Comment: If your array bounds are `[7][5]` then `i` and `j` seem reversed here don't they? `arr[i][j] = random_num(ran);`

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong indexes for the nested loops. C/C++ is a row-first language. A 2D array could be shown as:

```
arr[3][4] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
    {9, 10, 11, 12}
}
```

So, `arr[0]` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `arr[0][2]` will be `3`.

In order to randomize all elements, your outer loop should be `for each row` as you will iterate through arrays first. And inner loop should be `for each column` as you will iterate inside one of the inner arrays.

Pseudo code is:

```
for each row in the array
    for each column in the row
        [row][column] = random
```

And the fix is:

```
int r = 7; //Declares number of rows
int c = 5; //Declares number of columns
int arr[7][5]; //Initializes the array
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = random_num(ran);
    }
}
```